# What is the effect of imaginary quadratic extension on a quaternion algebra's ramified primes

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ramification, prime-ideals, quaternion-algebras

*A smart man once explained to me how to solve the following problem, then I forgot.*

Let $F\subset\mathbb{R}$
be a number field,
let $d\in F^+$,
and let $K=F(\sqrt{-d})$.
Denote the rings of integers of $F$
and $K$
respectively
by $\mathbb{Z}_F$
and $\mathbb{Z}_K$.
Suppose $\mathfrak{p}\vartriangleleft\mathbb{Z}_F$
is a prime ideal.
Then there exists some prime ideal $\mathfrak{P}\vartriangleleft\mathbb{Z}_K$
such that one of the following things is true.

1. $\mathfrak{p}\mathbb{Z}_K=\mathfrak{P}$
2. $\mathfrak{p}\mathbb{Z}_K=\mathfrak{P}^2$
3. $\mathfrak{p}\mathbb{Z}_K=\mathfrak{P}\overline{\mathfrak{P}}$

Now let $\mathcal{A}$
be a quaternion algebra over $F$
that is ramified at the place corresponding to $\mathfrak{p}$,
and let $\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{A}\otimes_FK$
(the quaternion algebra over $K$
resulting from the extension of scalars).

Is $\mathcal{B}$
ramified at $\mathfrak{P}$ (and at $\overline{\mathfrak{P}}$ in case 3)?
Why or why not?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The base change of your quaternion algebra will be ramified at $\mathfrak{P}$ if and only the degree of the extension of completions $K_{\mathfrak{P}}/F_{\mathfrak{p}}$ has odd degree, i.e. case 3. A general way to see this kind of property is that the invariant in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ of the class in the Brauer group gets multiplied by the degree when you base-change the corresponding algebra. A more down-to-earth proof in the case of quaternion algebra is to use the standard presentation of the division quaternion algebra over the local field $F_{\mathfrak{p}}$ and to see that it contains all the quadratic extensions of $F_{\mathfrak{p}}$; in case 3 the local extension is trivial and so locally there is no base-change at all.

---

**Edit:** Here are some references. Purely on $p$-adic fields, I guess Serre's *Local fields*. On quaternion algebras, there is the classic *Algèbre de quaternions* by Vignéras, but it is in French; there is the forthcoming book on quaternion algebras by John Voight, which is looking to be amazing; given your taste for geometry, I would also recommend the excellent *The arithmetic of hyperbolic three-manifolds* by Maclachlan and Reid, that contains very nice chapters on the local structure and the arithmetic of quaternion algebras. On more general central simple algebras and Brauer groups, I like the section in Milne's Class Field Theory notes, but this material is also contained in many textbooks.

Comment: I think my problem is that I don't know enough about $p$-adic fields. Maybe you know of a good source to get to the heart of my interest here. I recall a theorem about $A_\mathfrak{p}$ containing all quadratic extensions of $F_\mathfrak{p}$. It seems to me though like $K_\mathfrak{P}$ is among those quadratic extensions in cases 1 and 2.

Comment: Wait, right. If $K_\mathfrak{P}\hookrightarrow A_\mathfrak{p}$, then $d$ can be chosen as a structure parameter of $A_\mathfrak{p}$ up to isomorphism. Then $A_\mathfrak{p}\otimes K_\mathfrak{P}$ (which equals $B_\mathfrak{P}$) is split. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Comment: @j0equ1nn I added some references.

Comment: I happen to have checked out that Serre book from the library just before seeing the references you added. Also it happens that John Voight is the "smart man" I referred to in my question! I proofread most of the 1st 10 chapters of his book for him, but this subject comes a little later. I've just talked to him again and I'm basicaly going to keep reading where I left off to learn this stuff. In short, thanks for the references, they seem to me very tastefully selected.

Comment: You are welcome! Indeed if you can talk to JV, that is probably one of the fastest ways to learn about quaternion algebra. :-)